# "How may I help you" or "may I help you"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> 1. How may I help you?
> 2. May I help you?

Do these two statements have the same meaning or do they differ?  I could find no difference yet wanted to know anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

In the first question person A asks person B **in what way** he can help. In the second, he is simply asking **if** he can help.